# FBSDKGameRequestContent requires user to login again

Tags: ios, facebook

In iOS app user logs in to facebook and have active access token then I want to invite his friends to a specific challenge so I get his invitable friends Every thing works well to this point
then I open FBSDKGameRequestContent to make invitation it shows login dialog , 
My question I need to set my access token in FBSDKGameRequestContent ??

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
  gameRequestContent.message = @"Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!";
  gameRequestContent.to = @[@"RECIPIENT_USER_ID"];
  gameRequestContent.objectID = @"YOUR_OBJECT_ID";

  // Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
  [FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:self];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.4

Comment: What version of Facebook SDK are you using? and also the iOS version?

Comment: On verifying it seems like the Game request is using a webview. Once the user logs in using the webview, the login dialog should not show again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed issue at [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1072#event-2707261547) github, which stays that this is [not an issue](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1072#issuecomment-541202074), rather expected behaviour to prevent the user's data leak.